# Underscore: How to return all values by array with keys

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have big object with a lot of `key : value`, and I have array with some keys from this object.

How to return values of this `keys(array)` by underscore?

I try some like this, but it's bull**

```
_.find(objectwithkeysandvalues ,  function(value){
    return _.intersection(value,arraywithekeys)
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need Underscore for this task. Instead, you can use the [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function to create a new array that contains the values specified by the keys in the old array:

```
var myValues = keys.map(function (key) {
    return myObject[key]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need to [map](http://underscorejs.org/#map) each `value` from your keys array to `yourBigObject[value]`.

In Underscore this would look like this :

```
var keys = [ ... ]; // Keys from your big object
var obj = { ... }; // Your big object
var values = _.map(keys, function(value, index) {
    return obj[value];
});
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b5Lzev7n/) for experimenting.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using upcoming EcmaScript 7 Array Comprehensions available today via Babel.js.

Try it: [Array Comprehensions Example](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=true&evaluate=true&loose=true&spec=true&code=%20%20%20%20var%20obj%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22key1%22%3A%201%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22key2%22%3A%202%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22key3%22%3A%203%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20var%20arr%20%3D%20%5B%22key1%22%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20var%20values%20%3D%20%5Bfor(key%20of%20arr)%20obj%5Bkey%5D%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(values)%3B).

ES7:

```
var obj = {
  "key1": 1,
  "key2": 2,
  "key3": 3
}

var arr = ["key1"];

var values = [for(key of arr) obj[key]];

console.log(values);
```